# Creating JSON Code Resource

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, cloudpage, cloud

**Description:**
I am trying to create a Cloud Page Cloud Resource (JSON) that returns JSON data to a front-end client. I have started with this test endpoint, however, I does not return the JSON or display any to the front end for that matter.

Here is the code snippet from the cloud page:

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1")
  var test = Stringify({test: 'test'});
</script>

<ctrl:var name:test />
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write, as @DucLe stated will work and honestly is what I usually end up using, but the reason your code did not work is because you put `:` instead of `=` in your ctrl.

So if you were to change that and use the below, it should display as you wanted:

```js
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1")
  var test = Stringify({test: 'test'});
</script>

<ctrl:var name=test />
```

I also would highly recommend using double quotes in your JSON as that is the correct syntax and using the single quotes can sometimes have unexpected behaviors happen.

So from `{test: 'test'}` to `{test: "test"}`.

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue. That is why the four-eye principle is so important!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Write function to make it return to the Code Resource page

Try this:

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1")
  var test = Stringify({test: 'test'});
  Write(test);

  /* Or do like this:
  Write(Stringify({test: 'test'}))
  */
</script>
```

Return:

```
{"test":"test"}
```

Comment: I would like the result from the Code Resource return to the calling application.